# Docker container not running over browser

Tags: spring, docker, spring-mvc, dockerfile

I have containerized my application locally through docker. It is a spring mvc app and it starts successfully

```
 Web application available (default_host): http://479c9c236b5f:9080/ibm/saml20/
[AUDIT   ] CWWKT0016I: Web application available (default_host): http://479c9c236b5f:9080/IIT/
[AUDIT   ] CWWKZ0001I: Application IIT started in 10.076 seconds.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKF0012I: The server installed the following features: [appSecurity-2.0, appSecurity-3.0, cdi-2.0, distributedMap-1.0, el-3.0, federatedRegistry-1.0, jndi-1.0, jsp-2.3, ldapRegistry-3.0, localConnector-1.0, samlWeb-2.0, servlet-4.0, ssl-1.0, transportSecurity-1.0].
[AUDIT   ] CWWKF0011I: The defaultServer server is ready to run a smarter planet. The defaultServer server started in 26.691 seconds.
```

I used command docker run -p 8080:8080 my-docker to run my image but when i hit http://localhost:8080/IIT/ in browser it errors our saying "Connection was reset".

Comment: You web application is running on port 9080 and not 8080...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about spring-mvc, But as per your description it's look like in In container application using (http://479c9c236b5f:9080) 9080 port and outside you are using 8080 port.

Please apply `docker run -p 8080:9080 my-docker` for access it.
and if you are using Dockerfile please mention `EXPOSE 9080` in Dockerfile also.

Comment: I have exposed 9080 n my dockerfile. And now when i hit localhost:9080/IIT/ the browser still gives unable to connect

Comment: Why You are hitting localhost:9080, 9080 is container inner port where application is running. You have to hit localhost:8080 because 8080 is outer port where application traffic is coming.

Comment: Sorry. My bad. mentioned the wrong port Hitting 8080 also leads to the same issue.